# jquery datatables highlight cell based on its is column name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I am using https://www.datatables.net/ plugin.
This is my sample data for individual row

```
{
    id: 12,
    name: 'Fred',
    highlight: ['name'] // highlight column with name key
}
```

Highlight key indicated which key to highlight, in this case name column.

**PROBLEM:**
I know i can use rowCallBack and manipulate cells there but I cant seem to figure out how can i find cell`s column name so I can highlight it.

**OBJECTIVE:**
How do I find each cell`s column name so I can check if it exists in highlight array then add highlight class red

**JSFIDDLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/oLjy0rmL/

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //
  var data = [{
    id: 12,
    name: 'Fred',
    highlight: ['name'] // highlight column with name key
  }, {
    id: 13,
    name: 'Simon',
    highlight: []
  }, {
    id: 14,
    name: 'Albert',
    highlight: ['name']
  }];
  //
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "columns": [{
      'title': 'ID',
      'data': 'id',
      'name': 'id',
    }, {
      'title': 'Name',
      'data': 'name',
      'name': 'name',
    }],
    data: data,
    rowCallback: function(row, data, index) {
      var _hasHighlight = data.highlight && data.highlight.length;
      if (_hasHighlight) {
        $(row).find('td').each(function() {
          //how do I find each cell`s column name so i can check
          //if it exists in _hasHighlight array then add highlight class red 
        });
      }
    }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(row).find('td').each(function() {
```

Can you please try replacing the above line of code with the below one, which will give the columns names.

```
$(row).find('td').each(function (colIndex) {
alert($('#example').DataTable.arguments[0].columns[colIndex].title);
```

[Fiddler Link](https://jsfiddle.net/oLjy0rmL/10/)

Comment: title is not necessarily name key. I need column name not title as title could be anything.

Comment: change .title to .name

Comment: alert($('#example').DataTable.arguments[0].columns[colIndex].name);

Comment: wait, if column reordering is enabled then this would be wrong

Comment: can u explain what is .DataTable.arguments[0]  ??